# Python performance on reading files with extremely long lines

Tags: python, performance, file

I've got a file with around 6MB of data. All of the data are written in a single line. Why is the following command taking more than 15 minutes to finish? Is it normal?

```
infile = open('file.txt')
outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')
for line in infile.readlines():
    outfile.write(line);
```

**Details:**

I'm using Python 2.7.

Output from **wc**:

- newline count: 2
- word count: 3475246
- byte count: 6951140

**Evaluation 1:**

*Reference* code using in file (suggestted by Ahsanul Haque and Daewon Lee):

```
for line in infile:
    output.write(line):
```

*Time: 959.487 secs.*

Comment: this definitely seems fishy ... but `outfile` isn't opened in the correct mode for writing ...

Comment: Sorry. I've mistyped.

Comment: Can you please calculate number of characters in that line and put it in question? Will be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a lot of other disk writes going on?

Comment: No, my server is pretty empty.

Comment: `for line in infile:output.write(line)` takes how much time? It should be faster.

Comment: `readlines()` returns a list, which means the entire file is held in memory.  If you use the file handle as the iterator instead then, in theory, that should only read one line at a time.  Buffering might mean that more than that is actually  read.  `for line in infile:`

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Thanks for the suggestion. However, seems not to have a major effect. So far it already took 959 secs (16 minutes)

Comment: @rkioji Does your text file have just two new line characters (i.e., \n)?

Comment: @DaewonLee Yes, it has just two breaklines

Comment: I think your environment seems to have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet. The `readlines()` loads all data on memory, which seems to cause a long time.

```
infile = open('file.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')
for line in infile:
    outfile.write(line)
```

With my python 3.5 (64bit) on Windows 10 OS, the following code snippet finished within a few seconds.

```
import time

start = time.time()

with open("huge_text.txt", "w") as fout:
    for i in range(1737623):
        fout.write("ABCD ")
    fout.write('\n')   
    for i in range(1737623):
        fout.write("EFGH ")
    fout.write('\n')
# end of with

infile = open('huge_text.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')
for line in infile:
    outfile.write(line)

outfile.close()
infile.close()

end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: ", end - start)

"""
<Output>
Time elapsed:  1.557690143585205
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, seems not to have a major effect. So far it already took 959 secs (16 minutes).

Comment: hardware matters, if you have old pc components with many limitations then i will execute slowly.

Answer (score 0):

try reading file in chunks

```
infile = open('file.txt')
outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')
while True:
    text = infile.read(100): # or any other size
    if not text:
        break
    outfile.write(line);
```